# Alignment column on excel

Tags: excel, alignment

I import any data from a txt file but some cell is not aligned.

[image]

I want to align all cell with "Normale"

Exemple from this

[image]

Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: Please share the text file, I think the way it is imported is the cause of the misalignment.

Comment: When you import the TXT or CSv in the proper fashion, turn **off** the option to *Treat consecutive delimiters as one*.

Comment: This is a txt file [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/p3qrw1). The data is copied from an HTML file. @Jeeped i have turned off the option "Treat consecutive delimiters as one"

Comment: Finally the simplest I've found, is to change the txt. Find all "Normal" and play whith tab, remove and enter...